# how to disable default FileAppender logback rollingpolicy

Tags: logback

please find my application logback FileAppender configuration.

```
     <appender name="ALERT-FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
            <file>application-alert.log</file>
            <append>true</append>
            <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
                    <level>ERROR</level>
            </filter>
            <encoder>
                    <pattern>%date{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %msg%n</pattern>
            </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="ALERT" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="ALERT-FILE" />
    </logger>
```

I didn't configure any rollingpolicy for ALERT-FILE appender, but still rolling is happening. I need a single file for all my ERROR through out the day year etc. 
Please help.

Thanks 
Satyajit

Comment: your configuration seems correct for no rolling; are you sure you did repackage your program with the updated logback config?

Comment: yes, I have rebuild and tested many times. In that same logback.xml file I have another file appender which is having regular logging as well as rollingPolicy.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an environmental issue - the environment you launch your application in, like Linux, can have some logs-handling routines that provide automatic rolling for files located in `logs` directory.

Answer (score 0):

try to add `rollingPolicy` section to appender config

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <File>/var/log/tomcat/app.log</File>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>/var/log/tomcat/app.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
```